# c# filter for multiple lines

Tags: c#, linq

Hey guys I need some help;
I have `something.txt` that contains

```
4   10:06:29      0      0          0

2   10:06:30      0      0          0

9   10:06:31      0      0          0

4   10:06:32      0      0          0

7   10:06:31      0      0          0
```

something in format like that

then I have some code

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
var lines1 = File.ReadAllLines(path).First(s => s.StartsWith(tempvar));
listBox1.Items.Add(lines1);
```

I need to filter (grap) multiple lines that start with number 4 (for example)
my code does this for the first line that he found in file (.txt file), need some help for multiple lines

Comment: So what is wrong with the code you have shown?

Comment: You tell it to read the first line that starts with your filter `var lines1 = File.ReadAllLines(path).First(s => s.StartsWith(tempvar));`. If you change that to `var lines1 = File.ReadAllLines(path).Where(s => s.StartsWith(tempvar)).ToList();` I think it should return all the lines that start with the filter.

Comment: Why do you create a reader for the file and then just use `File.ReadAllLines` instead?

Comment: ahh yeah i copy some code that i comment later for next use; ill try this now, i try before with trim() and got many other version of code, but none do what i want, thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

Replacing `First` with `Where` in the Linq query should do it.

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
var listBox1 = File.ReadAllLines(path).Where(s => s.StartsWith(tempvar)).ToList();
```

Comment: And you don't even need the first line of that, since your "file" field isn't used.

Comment: thanks, helps alot, i do something similar before, but without .ToList

Comment: Be sure that there is no space at start.